# Switch network with script MacOS

Tags: macos

Is there anyway in OSX to write a script that switches network preferences? I.E. switch from ethernet to wifi and back again.

I'm familiar with writing batch files in windows but cluess in MacOS

Comment: ask https://superuser.com!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to have already defined locations and then just do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "No arguments, try one of this:"; networksetup -listlocations
    echo "Current location: "; networksetup -getcurrentlocation
    exit 1
fi

eval networksetup -switchtolocation \"$@"\
```

If the network location was successfully changed it will print `found it!`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give this a whirl.

Comment: @RyanAthey I modified it to accept location with spaces, but well hope can give you an idea :-)